# Multiple functions with toggle Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a slider. I have two divs, left arrow and right arrow.

My idea is that when the left or the right arrow is clicked, the `div` that is active is hidden and the other view is displayed.
I am doing this with `toggle()`, and it hides the first view, but it doesn't show the second view.

And it needs to go smoothly, like a carousel.

Here is my JQuery:

```
$("#test2").hide();

$("#left").click(function(){
  $("#test1").toggle("slide", function(){
    $("#test1").show();
    $("#test2").hide();

  }, function(){
    $("#test2").show();
    $("#test1").hide();
  });
});
```

Here is an example of the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="left></div>
  <div id="test1">image + text</div>
  <div id="test2">image + text</div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are calling the exact opposite function of function "A" on callback *(function "B")*... And there is not delay in millisecond between parenthesis of `show()` and `hide()`. What do you expect as a result except nothing? Ever heard about "double negation" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your JavaScript is incorrect. The changes below should get you where you want to be:

**Demo Link**

[Working JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jessejjohnson/pte3dbgr/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="left">LEFT</div>
  <div id="test1">image + text 1</div>
  <div id="test2">image + text 2</div>
  <div id="right">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $test1 = $("#test1");
var $test2 = $("#test2");

$("#test2").hide();

$("#left").click(function() {
  toggleViews($test2, $test1);
});

$("#right").click(function() {
  toggleViews($test1, $test2);
});

function toggleViews(viewToHide, viewToShow) {
  $(viewToHide).hide("slide", function() {
    $(viewToShow).show("slide");
  });
}
```

Comment: This worked, but I can click only once per arrow. I can't click multiple times on the left arrow. It works only on the first try.

Comment: Nope. This script works only for one click in each direction alternatively.

Comment: @Spirit_Scarlet Was hoping to get you a starting point and demonstrate how you can smoothly transition between elements. Will just go between the two div's but should be fairly easy to expand by using [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how a "toggle" works.
This example implies a CSS class toggle from "there" (applied on the element) or absent.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="left></div>
  <div id="test1">image + text</div>
  <div id="test2" class="hidden">image + text</div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#left, #right").click(function(){
  $(".row div[id^='test']").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

The `^=` operator means "begin with".